# Prestashop home page not visible

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have installed Prestashop 1.7.5.1. and it finished successfully.
I can view my admin login page and log in as administrator, but when I try to go to my home page only a blank document is displayed.

What am I doing wrong? What Have I change?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to turn on "Debug mode" to display errors.

[How to turn on error reporting in PrestaShop](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/224525-how-to-turn-on-error-reporting-for-debug-information-blank-page-500-internal-server-error/)